# Slurm and mpi4py : repeat n times the operation with one process instead of doing it one time with n process

Tags: python, slurm, mpi4py

I'm a new user of Slurm and mpi4py so I wanted to test a little code I found here : https://researchcomputing.princeton.edu/mpi4py

My python code `test.py` is the following :

```
from mpi4py import MPI
import sys

def print_hello(rank, size, name):
  msg = "Hello World! I am process {0} of {1} on {2}.\n"
  sys.stdout.write(msg.format(rank, size, name))

if __name__ == "__main__":
  size = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Get_size()
  rank = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Get_rank()
  name = MPI.Get_processor_name()

  print_hello(rank, size, name)
```

And my bash script is :

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --job-name=mpi4py-test 
#SBATCH --nodes=1                
#SBATCH --ntasks=3              
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=1 

srun python test.py
```

When running `sbatch run.sh` I expected to get something like :

```
Hello World! I am process 0 of 3 on node1.
Hello World! I am process 1 of 3 on node1.
Hello World! I am process 2 of 3 on node1.
```

However I get :

```
Hello World! I am process 0 of 1 on node1.
Hello World! I am process 0 of 1 on node1.
Hello World! I am process 0 of 1 on node1.
```

And if I change `srun python test.py` by `srun mpiexec -n 3 python test.py` I get :

```
Hello World! I am process 0 of 3 on node1.
Hello World! I am process 2 of 3 on node1.
Hello World! I am process 1 of 3 on node1.
Hello World! I am process 1 of 3 on node1.
Hello World! I am process 0 of 3 on node1.
Hello World! I am process 2 of 3 on node1.
Hello World! I am process 0 of 3 on node1.
Hello World! I am process 1 of 3 on node1.
Hello World! I am process 2 of 3 on node1.
```

The process was executed 3 times but I just want it to be executed once.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be because either

- Mpi4py is using a version of MPI that was not compiled with Slurm support ; or
- you have a very old OpenMPI ; or
- you have a very old Slurm.

Running

```
mpiexec -n 3 python test.py
```

will probably get you what you want.

Comment: Thanks, It was indeed because I used the `srun` in front of the `mpiexec` command, now it works.